# Programmatically load openjpa javaagent - runtime optimization

Tags: openjpa

I am writing unit test for testing JPA DAO and I would like to automatically load the javaagant (JPA class enhancer) without having to specify the -javaagent vm parameter.

To achieve this I implemented a @BeforeClass annotated method like this:

```
    String nameOfRunningVM = ManagementFactory.getRuntimeMXBean().getName();
    String pid = nameOfRunningVM.substring(0, nameOfRunningVM.indexOf('@'));
    VirtualMachine vm = VirtualMachine.attach(pid);
    vm.loadAgent("openjpa-all-2.4.2.jar");
    vm.detach();
    emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("TEST_DB");
```

But I still get the error telling entity classes were not enhanced when creating the entity manager factory.

> org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: This configuration disallows runtime optimization, but the following listed types were not enhanced at build time or at class load time with a javaagent: ")

I can live with the -javaagent parameter but I am curious and would be pleased if anybody could share a solution or idea with us.

I am running my test with JUnit and Java 8

Comment: It is working fine when running the test on the command line with maven but fails when started from IDE (Intellij)

Comment: Now running fine with intelliJ since I cleaned up the run configuration.   Reason of failure was probably due to intelliJ agent library loading.